# Sublime Text 2 OSX Grunt build system woe

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, gruntjs

I'm trying to use Sublime Text 2s build system to run a Grunt task. I have no issues using Grunt within Terminal. My setup works well on my Windows machine but my Mac hates it.

This is my .sublime-build configuration:

```
{
  "selector": "grunt.js",
  "working_dir": "${project_path}/js",
  "windows": {
    …
  },
  "osx": {
    "cmd": ["grunt", "--no-color"]
  }
}
```

And the output returned is:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The working directory and path returned are correct. My software versions are:

- OSX 10.8.2
- Node 0.8.9
- NPM 1.1.68
- Grunt 0.3.17
- Sublime Text 2.0.1

Please save me any more frustrated Googling!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure `grunt` is in your `path` with sublime (it can be different then your terminal path). To find the path type: `npm bin -g`. You can set the path in your sublime-build config:

```
{
  "selector": "grunt.js",
  "working_dir": "${project_path}",
  "path": "/usr/local/bin",
  "osx": {
    "cmd": ["grunt", "--no-color"]
  }
}
```

Just a nitpick, set the `working_dir` to the base project path. Not important as grunt will find up until it reaches a gruntfile but that will find the gruntfile slightly faster ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response - one way or another it now works OK (without-so far-adjusting the ST2 path). Ideally I would just set the working directory to the project path (it's a sane tip!) but that doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: I'm still getting an error from Sublime: `You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for
this task to work.` I'm not getting this error in the terminal, just sublime...

Comment: Do a `which ruby` to find the location of Ruby, which was in `/usr/bin` for me.  Here's my full sublime-build file: `{
    "cmd": ["grunt", "--no-color"],
    "selector": ["gruntfile.js"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path}",
    "path": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"
}`